# SQL join 3 tables grouped with latest group value

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have 3 tables. User, messages and user_analytics with the following structure:

- user (userId) - contains all users
- message (messageId(pk),userId(fk),time) - contains all messages
- user_analytics (user_analyticsId(pk),userId(fk),device,time) -
  contains data collected on connection

> ```
> user : messages (1:n)
> user : device (1:n)
> ```

Now I would like to know how many messages were sent on each day with what device. Therefor I first need to collect for each message the device (desktop,iOS,Android) used to send the message depending on the message time itself. This means I need user_analytics.time <= message.time and display the latest result.

I saw a lot solutions about greatest-n-per-group but I didn't get it to work.

I only get it to work with a subquery which takes 20 seconds (user_analytics holds 100k records and message 3k... so not much):

```
select  date_format(m.time,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
        count(*) as message_count,
        ua.device
from    message m,
        user u left join user_analytics ua on (
            u.userId = ua.userId and
            ua.user_analyticsId = ( select max(user_analyticsId) 
                                from    user_analytics
                                where   userId = m.userId and
                                        time < m.time))
where   m.userId = u.userId
group by 1,3;
```

But this looks highly inefficient. Any other ways to achieve the same result?

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to mention that I have a important condition on user table. That is why I need the join to this table.

I created a sql fiddle to give you an example. For now I already implemented [Jaguar Chang's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27329987/641769) solution which is 100 times faster than mine:

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9395c/1)

Comment: I need you to address some ambiguities before I can answer the question. If you had only wanted to "now how many messages were sent on each day with what device", your query doesn't seem to answer to that. Can you be a little more explicit as to what data are you trying to achieve? Next, what is this "user_analytics.time <= message.time" criteria about?

Comment: Use an uncorrelated subquery instead

Comment: The answers below look good, but for more help consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: "which is 100 times faster than mine:" and produces the desired result?

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes it now takes 0.7 seconds (so it feels like 100 times compared to the 20 seconds before) I wonder how it will perform when the data grows.

Comment: @Calvintwr: "now how many messages were sent on each day with what device" is exaclty what I want and my query (with subquery) as well as Jaguar Chang's solution return this result. And "user_analytics.time <= message.time" means I want the latest device used according to the message time since the time in user_analytics is not equal than the message time and also can be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no necessity of joining user table, so you could simplify your code like this:

```
select  date_format(m.time,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
        count(*) as message_count,
        ua.device
from    message m,
        left join user_analytics ua on (
            m.userId = ua.userId and
            ua.user_analyticsId = ( select max(user_analyticsId) 
                                from    user_analytics
                                where   userId = m.userId and
                                        time < m.time))
group by 1,3;
```

This may not efficient enough, but you could try this:

```
select  date_format(t2.time,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
        count(*) as message_count,
        t2.last_device
from    
    (select 
      @device := 
          if(@uid = userid,
             if(tbl = 'm' ,@device, device),
             if(@uid := userid,device,device)) as last_device
      ,t1.*
      from 
          (select @device := '' , @uid :=0) as t0
      join
          (select 'ua' as tbl,userid,time,device from user_analytics
           union all
           select 'm' as tbl,userid,time,null as device from messages
          ) as t1
      order by userid,time
    ) as t2
where tbl='m'
group by 1,3;
```

I guess your original purpose is to divide messages by the times of connection on device, so order the messages and connection record by time series together, then you could get the device used by last connection for every message.

I think this approach will be much efficient, since 100k+3k sorting will be much faster than 3k*100k*100k join operations

A test [**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afb02f2/3).

Comment: Nice solution thx, do you see a problem with sorting once data grows (the analytics table grows 100k each year)?

Comment: I think the historical data will never be changed. So there's no necessary of resorting those historical data, just expand the result to your message table.

Answer (score 1):

So how does this compare (probably less favourably as the dataset grows...)

```
SELECT DATE(message_time) dt
     , b.device
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM 
     (
       SELECT m.id message_id
            , m.userid
            , m.time message_time
            , MAX(um.time) device_time
         FROM messages m
         JOIN user_analytics um
           ON um.userid = m.userid
          AND um.time <= m.time
        GROUP 
           BY m.id
      ) a
  JOIN user_analytics b
    ON b.userid = a.userid
   AND b.time = a.device_time
 GROUP
    BY DATE(message_time)
     , b.device;
```

Comment: Thx for your solution. It works (expect of that messages with no device information should be displayed as device: null as you can see in my fiddle). I think changing the 'JOIN user_analytics um' to 'LEFT JOIN user_analytics um' would solve it). I tried it on 100k and the query takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes - aright join in this instance - but you could just as easily swap the two parts of the query around. An index on (userid,time) in the analytics table woould help immensely

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you wanted, but you said your query is working you just wanted an efficient way. so ust try this n let me know if it works

```
select  date_format(m.time,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
        count(*) as message_count,
        ua.device, max(ua.user_analyticsId)
from    message m
        INNER JOIN
        user u ON
        m.userId = u.userId
        LEFT JOIN 
        user_analytics ua ON
        u.userId = ua.userId and       
where  
ua.time<m.time
group by 1,3;
```

you can ignore the new column added if you want by putting entire query in from block of another query

```
select date, message_count, device from (
    select  date_format(m.time,'%Y-%m-%d') as date,
            count(*) as message_count,
            ua.device, max(ua.user_analyticsId)
    from    message m
            INNER JOIN
            user u ON
            m.userId = u.userId
            LEFT JOIN 
            user_analytics ua ON
            u.userId = ua.userId and       
    where  
    ua.time<m.time
    group by 1,3) A ;
```

Comment: I'll appreciate corrective and informative comments on above query(if any)

Comment: Your query returns error code 1054, unknown column ua.user_analyticsId in having clause.

Comment: thanks to your effort but it returns not the desired result and takes also 15 seconds on my 100k data (I added a sql fiddle demostrating the desired result)